# /data/data nightmare: FC's because of 100% Utilisation 

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, internal-storage, force-close

I feel like I need to clear things from /data/data every 2 to 3 days to prevent cascading FCs when it becomes 100% full. Is there any possible way to move any of that data to the SD card (and still have it be accessible from my apps), or to increase the maximum size of the folder? I am rooted and running cyanogenmod 7.1 on my HTC Incredible. Thank you all so much for your assistance.

Comment: I have the same problem occasionally, though not as often as 2 - 3 days, more like every couple weeks. its more the /data/cache directory that gets full for me too, as I do a wipe of the cache and I am fine for a while. How many apps do you have installed? This is very annoying, and I will be watching this to see if there are any solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried moving your Apps to the SD Card?  Go to `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Downloaded tab` then tap on any 3rd-party app and then tap on the `Move to SD card` button (if available.)  This should move most of the app to the card, thus freeing up space on the /data/ partition.  Not all apps support this method, but do try it on the largest space hogs like Flash Player and Adobe Air, for example.

Unfortunately moving Apps to SD Card this way doesn't touch the apps' cache or Dalvik cache.  To move those you'd need the old-school "apps2sd" hack.  The basic idea is to re-partition your SD Card and create a 2nd partition with Ext2/3/4 format.  The contents of /data/ folders are moved to the SD Card's Ext partition and the phone's internal memory is therefore freed up.  Then a script is added to Android which mounts this partition at boot time and links /data/app, /data/app-private, /data/data, and /data/dalvik-cache folders to their corresponding locations on the SD Card's Ext partition.

There are some apps on the Market that automate this (except re-partitioning the card, which you'll need to do manually.)  Try [Link2sd](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) or [Simple2ext](https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e) for example.  Of course make sure you have a nandroid backup of your phone before trying anything.

There are obvious pros and cons to this method. The pros are the ability to greatly extend the phone's storage for apps, while keeping the internal memory relatively free.  The cons are inability to cleanly un-mount and remove the SD Card (since the apps are mounted on the 2nd partition that the OS isn't aware of,) and possible slow-downs in launching apps depending on the speed of the card.  There SD Card will also be subjected to more wear and tear, since it will be used by the system for reading/writing more than usual.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is definitely the best answer for me. I will try it out and see if it is worth the performance hit.

Comment: @LauraBooth How did it turn out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Obb2sd. App available on Google play. Writes your app data for each downloaded app (including Google apps that come preinstalled in most androids) onto your external sd.

Have a good file manager, and one of the first few folders will be labeled 'android' and have 2 sub folders - 'data' and 'obb'. These record all your user activity and can fill up memory very fast. Every map, every song, every search, every level you play, every achievement, and sometimes app resources as well are in these folders. The 'obb' folder usually contains the ever-increasing data from some of your downloaded apps.

If you have external SD, a similar 'android' folder exists but the 'obb' folder doesn't always contain the data from apps you moved to SD. Some apps by default ONLY write your internal memory and OBB2SD changes that permission.

Totally solved my memory dilemma.