# Multiple force closes

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, force-close, cellular-radio

I have intermittent issues with multiple apps forcing closing. This has happened on both my current ROM (Miui) and every version of Cyanogenmod I've tried.

Usually this problem crops up again a few months after a fresh ROM install or factory reset. I'll switch from 3G to Wifi, or vise versa, and then everything on my phone that uses background data will start force closing. The most usual suspects are Google Services Framework (com.google.process.gapps) and Facebook (com.facebook.katana), but almost any app seems to force close including ScoreCenter, Docs, and Smooth Calendar.

In addition to the force closes, the other big symptom is that I can't turn off or on airplane mode, mobile network data (3G), wifi, or background data syncing - but usually not all at the same time. Sometimes I'll be able to turn on Wifi but not airplane mode, or other times I'll be able to turn 3G off but Wifi won't turn off. Sometimes I'll be able to turn a service off or on after a reboot, other times not. Sometimes when I reboot a service that I turned off before will be back on again, other times not. Incredibly, utterly frustrating.

Neither rebooting, fixing permissions, nor wiping dalvik cache seem to help. I've only ever gotten my phone to work again by fiddling around with the radio settings and pulling the battery for hours before something magically starts working again. This most recent time I've even removed my Google account from the phone but that hasn't helped either. I know a factory reset would make this problem go away (for a little while, at least) but it always returns - I want to find the root cause and change whatever is making it happen in the first place (especially if it's something *I'm* doing!).

I know that this issue involves the interaction between app syncing and the wifi/3G radios but I have no idea what or why. I've uploaded a [logcat here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=11i9mayA23jtV7gxAmQC9_DZJh_37IUiaPjAaHqDHIgk) - I hope you all can make heads or tails of it. I saw `E/ACRA    ( 1296): java.io.IOException: No space left on device` and presumed it might be a partition storage space issue but all the partitions I could see (including those that require root) still have space.

Thanks in advance, I'm super frustrated with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating further and looking at the partitions again, it turns out that I did have a totally full /data/data (as described [in a previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14707/data-data-nightmare-fcs-because-of-100-utilisation)).

For posterity, here's what I did:

Because [DiskUsage](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en), the app I normally use to investigate partition usage, had locked up as well I fired up [Terminal Emulator](https://market.android.com/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) (luckily it was still working) and followed this advice I found in [an XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1264177&page=2):

> You can check [the partition utilization] by running this command as root:
>
> `df /data/data`
>
> If you see % used = 100 then this is your problem.

It was, in fact, 100% full. As soon as I moved some apps to my SD card my phone immediately started working again. I must've misread the free space of the partition when I first looked into it (doh!). The radio issues I was sure were involved ended up being a red herring.