# Updating Unsuccessful, but Phone memory reduced

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i rooted smartphone. I tried to update to the latest firmware update by the default update option in setting menu and it started downloading update file of 26MB. Now during updating it got stuck on 26% and the phone rebooted saying FIRMWARE UPDATE UNSUCCESSFUL.

I guess that it may be because my phone is rooted, but then I checked my phone space and found it reduced to 19 MB from 41 MB.

So what is taking that much space? Please help me free up some phone space.

Comment: Most likely the downloaded update-file is still stuck in your internal storage. I'm not sure were exactly it went to, but `/data/local` is a good guess if it didn't save to your sdcard. You might find some initial help here: [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575), also check [these questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage?sort=frequent).

Comment: /data/local contains only 1 folder /temp which is empty

Comment: OK, so that's not the place where "stuff got stuck". Was the other linked question helpful on your search? You might also want to check [Android “Internal Storage” used but not reported](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28110/16575) for more hints on locating "fillers".

Comment: I saw it, but still I 'm stuck on.how to solve my problem. As it happened after trying to update the phone I think it because of some file getting unzipped in the internal storage, I am just unable to locate it.

Comment: Which is why I was searching the other question for you, which I remembered includes several approaches on locating where the "big stuff" hides.