# Trouble moving apps to SD card

Tags: internal-storage, partitions, link2sd, internal-sd

I followed the instructions mentioned in this [site](http://www.aroundandroid.com/tag/how-to-increase-android-phones-internal-memory-with-link2sd-app/) and I partitioned my 8GB SD card alloting 512 MB to my second partition. I then used Link2SD and linked all my apps to SD card. Every time I install a new app I get the notification that the app is linked to SD. But my internal memory still get used up and I get the message "Low Internal Memory". After partitioning I set the Link2SD location to EXT2. But looks like my apps are not getting installed there. Appreciate any help! :)

Comment: How do you tell it "looks like apps are not getting installed there"? File manager? Or is it rather an assumption? One more thing to consider is: *Link2SD does not move application's private data files; it moves apk, dex (dalvik-cache) and lib files.* (from [Link2SD description at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). So it might rather be the apps' data filling up your internal storage.

Comment: Actually the apps are getting installed on to the ext4 partition. When I unmounted the partition the apps failed to show up in the drawer. So now why is my internal memeory still getting used up? I am unable to install any new apps because it says "Insufficient storage avaliable" but my ext4 partition still has a lot of space remaining.

Comment: As I indicated in my previous comment, it's most likely app data. You might want to take a look at [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27127/16575) and [Android “Internal Storage” used but not reported](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28110/16575) for a closer investigation, also [most frequented "internal-storage" questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage) might prove helpful. PS: You might also want to update your question to fit the new facts :)